# Skew with Sgn(x) yields unwanted signed line segments

Tags: desmos

I'm using Desmos to visualize a concept, but I'm not getting what I expect.

- Assume we start with a morphed circle, in **green**, focusing only on the positive y values.
- We want to skew the green equal to its height (i.e. **purple**), from the center.  To do this I used **sgn(x)**.
- In red is a sample point on the green shape, of **{-.5, 1.9365}**.  The sample point is correctly mapped to the purple by subtracting the height from -.5: **-2.4365**.

[image: graph1]
[image: equations1]

However, I don't want to pull the data from positive x into negative x.  That is, if you think of the green graph as having 2 horns, one positive and one negative, how do you prevent having both horns on each side (like in purple)?

I want something like this, in **orange**, where I've removed unwanted segments of the line, scratched out in **black**.  Note:  I put a bounds to remove anything below |x|<1, since I wouldn't expect any values there.

You might say that it opens up like crab pincers, or a gate.

[image: graph2]
[image: equations2]

*Is there a way to do this?  To exclude positive x from the negative, and vice versa?*  I don't want to hide those segments, like with bounds.  I desire a way to change the equation so those overlapping values go away.

I assume it has something to do with utilizing the x values from the green equation, instead of the x value from the purple, but I don't know how this is accomplished.  I tried using x_1 and x_2, green and purple respectively, but Desmos didn't like that, or I was doing it wrong.  Specifically, sgn(x_1) would be green's x sign values, not purple's x sign values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized one of my assumptions was wrong.

```
I don't want to hide those segments, like with bounds.
```

I actually do have to use **bounds**, because I'm creating a *discontinuity* in the line.  To do this, the line has to be bounded at its limits.

1. First, I split the original shape into 2 sides (positive and negative x).  It's not necessary, but allowed me to think of both sides as being *independent* from one another (in **green**). I knew the break occurs at x = 0.  While this isn't a *removable discontinuity*, it is the last valid point before a *jump discontinuity* is created.
2. If I set the bounds correctly, in **orange** @ y and -y, the undesired parts of the graph go away because they are outside the valid range of values.  I also had to use 2 equations here to represent each side of the jump discontinuity.
3. Next, I made a dotted **orange** line that spans the newly created jump discontinuity.  This isn't necessary, but helps illustrate the gap.
4. Finally, I created 2 **orange** points to label each end of the jump discontinuity.

[image: graph1]
[image: equations1]